# Why does WriteFile need a delay to work or else ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER on certain Windows machines?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hid

I setup a device using `CreateFile` and send a report to a HID device using `WriteFile`. On my **Dell Precision 3520 PC** I do NOT need a sleep call in order to send my initial setup message to my device. However, after debugging on other Windows machines (an **Alienware** among the list) I found that I would get a failure trying to send that initial setup message unless I called `Sleep`.

It's actually a very special case:

- The HID device is establishing a BLE connection
- The device is initially off, then turned on, and the Windows event system finds the device arrival via a process callback to `WM_DEVICECHANGE`, which is where `CreateFile` and `WriteFile` send the setup report.
- This only happens on certain Windows machines

Here's some code to give you an idea of the error:

```
Sleep(500); // this allows me to send a message
BOOL Result = WriteFile(IOHandle, OutputReport, OutputReportSize, &bytesWritten, NULL);
if (Result)
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    d = GetLastError(); // This is 87 without Sleep
    CloseComm();
    return 1;
}
```

My Questions are:

**1. Why am I getting ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (87) unless Sleep is called**

**2. Why is this required on certain Windows machines**

Comment: call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` in place `GetLastError()` - what it return ?

Comment: @RbMm what's the header for that function?

Comment: no header file, but it have the same signature as `GetLastError`. so `extern "C" __declscpec(dllimport)
NTSTATUS
WINAPI
RtlGetLastNtStatus();` and include *ntdll.lib* to linker input

Comment: @RbMm it returns 87

Comment: no, you mistake - `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` not return 87. are you call it ?

Comment: is it an unsigned int? printf("debug: %u", RtlGetLastNtStatus())

Comment: this is signed int. and dump it as hex - so use `%x` format instead `%u`. of course really this not change result but in %x form value will be redable, in %u form - need be convert from dec to hex

Comment: 57 with that change

Comment: no, i ask you about `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` result, not about `GetLastError()` result. the `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` **never** return *0x57*